# Javascript object undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

my code keeps telling me an object I have created is undefined.

I am loading in several JS files then calling functions but it errors

The error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setListenUrl' of undefined

Here's the code:

```
<script src="{{ URL::asset('javascript/chat.js') }}"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        chatbox.setListenUrl('{{ URL::route('chat.listen') }}');
        chatbox.setSendURL('{{ URL::route('chat.send')  }}');

        @if(Auth::check())
        chatbox.setAuth(true);
        @endif

        @if(isset($game))
        chatbox.setGame('{{ $game }}');
        @endif

        chatbox.init();
    });
</script>
```

chat.js

```
var chatbox = {

...
}
```

Full script code
http://pastebin.com/7LhWq01U

chat.js
http://pastebin.com/nNgTtME1

Comment: So `chatbox` is clearly `undefined`, meaning your script isn't loading, or you did something wrong in it.

Comment: Can you please check whether your code is load by adding things like `console.log` in the end of your chat.js?

Comment: It is 100% loading, I added console.log in chat.js and before I called chat.setListenUrl and it appears in the right order.

Comment: Here's the URL if it helps http://178.62.26.90/bwaf2/public/

Answer (score 2):

You are using `chatbox` in the object literal that you assign to `chatbox`, that doesn't work because chatbox isn't yet defined.
That uncaught error makes the execution of your entire `chat.js` script stop, which is why `chatbox` is also `undefined` in the following scripts.

So, beginning at line 17 of `chat.js`, you have to find a way to reference `$chatbox` in multiple places of your object.
This is a common problem in JavaScript when you would like to reference a previously defined property in an object literal.
But the thing is that you can't, so for now the quickest fix would be to declare a `$chatbox` variable outside of your object and reference it from inside.

Since declaring global variables left and right is definitely bad practice, this problem can be better tackled in the following 2 ways:

#### Constructor functions

You create a [constructor function](https://css-tricks.com/understanding-javascript-constructors/) and then make instances of the object with the keyword `new`. This provides encapsulation of the object initialization code and allows you to create multiple chatbox objects easily if you ever need it.

```
function Chatbox() {
     var $chatbox = $('.chatbox');
     this.$chatbox = $chatbox;
     this.$input = $chatbox.find('.input input');          
     //...
}

var chatbox = new Chatbox();
```

If you know you won't have multiple instances of your object though, the constructor pattern doesn't provide much and may just be an additional syntax burden, so you can use a lighter encapsulation technique:

#### Immediately invoked function expression (IIFE)

You put all your object initialization code in an anonymous function that returns the object at the end, and you invoke that function right in a variable declaration statement, which also provides encapsulation of any variables you need to declare when initializing your object.

```
var chatbox = (function() {
      var $chatbox = $('.chatbox');

      return {
           $chatbox: $chatbox,
           $input: $chatbox.find('.input input'),
           //           ^ This references the outer $chatbox variable, not this
           //             object's $chatbox property.
      };

})();
```